# Angular run block, $rootScope.$on and $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, dom-events

I have a strange issue when I try create an eventhandler in the run block. It is a bit hard to explain the issue, partly because I don't understand what's happening but I will do my best. It's written in typescript.

I have the following run-block:

```
angular.module("myapp")
  .run(($rootScope, StateChangeStartHandler) => {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", StateChangeStartHandler.handler);
  });
```

`StateChangeStartHandler` is a simple angular service with a function called handler which is meant to handle the `$stateChangeStart` event. The handler service looks like this:

```
class StateChangeStartHandler {

  private AuthService;
  private $rootScope;
  private AUTH_EVENTS;

  constructor(AuthService, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS
             // Everything breaks if I comment in the following line
             //, $state
             ) {
    this.AuthService = AuthService;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.AUTH_EVENTS = AUTH_EVENTS;
  }

  handler(event, next) {
    if (!this.AuthService.isLoggedIn() && next.name != "root.login") {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.$rootScope.$broadcast(this.AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
    }
  }
}

angular.module("myapp")
  .service("StateChangeStartHandler", StateChangeStartHandler);
```

I was implementing this using TDD. I wrote a test that verified if go was called on `$state`. When I then went into the class to implement it, I faced the issue. When I injected `$state` in the `StateChangeStartHandler`, suddenly all tests using `$rootScope.$apply()` said `AuthService.isLoggedIn` is not a function.

I suspect that `$rootScope.$apply()` triggers a `$stateChangeStart`, and then something strange happens.

**UPDATE 1:**
An example of a seemingly unrelated test that suddenly fails:

```
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) Authentication service login(email, password) should be defined FAILED
    TypeError: this.AuthService.isLoggedIn is not a function
        at StateChangeStartHandler.handler (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/app.js:305:31)
        at Scope.$broadcast (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:16311:28)
        at Object.transitionTo (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:50779:24)
        at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:49896:18)
        at Object.invoke (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:4584:17)
        at handleIfMatch (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:49386:28)
        at /Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:49441:18
        at check (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:49557:23)
        at update (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:49566:13)
        at Scope.$broadcast (/Users/blacksails/repos/avalonia/priv/static/js/libraries.js:16311:28)
```

Comment: where's the `$apply`? Why do you ever need to call `$apply` on `$rootScope`? Usually done at more local level

Comment: I did that in a few tests of promises. There are a lot of other tests failing as well actually. I have a lot of tests using $httpBackend, all of these seem to fail on $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(), which in turn calls Scope.$digest

Answer (score 0):

try these:

```
    angular.module("myapp")
    .run(($rootScope, StateChangeStartHandler) => {
      $rootScope.$on
        ("$stateChangeStart",StateChangeStartHandler.handler.bind(StateChangeStartHandler);
    });
```

Comment: Does not change all of the failing tests.

Comment: you need to call broadcast like this: $broadcast("$stateChangeStart", data). And you have to call broadcast that something happends on $on not the other way

Comment: Why should I broardcast $stateChangeStart? Angular ui-router already does that automatically.

Comment: because you registered your $on like that. I don't see any ui-router setup. With broadcast you "call" what you setup in $on

Comment: Well the fact that I use ui-router is evident by the use of the $stateChangeStart and i also tagged the question angular-ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. I am not really sure about the technical details, but I think it's related to how angular lazy loads services. The following fixed my problem. Instead of referencing the function `handler` in `StateChangeStartHandler` like this,

```
angular.module("myapp")
  .run(($rootScope, StateChangeStartHandler) => {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", StateChangeStartHandler.handler);
  });
```

I made it a getter like this:

```
angular.module("myapp")
  .run(($rootScope, StateChangeStartHandler) => {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", StateChangeStartHandler.handler());
  });
```

I kept the function in a field in the `StateChangeStartHandler` and then `handler` merely returns that function. Without being sure at all, I suspect that when i passed the function like in the first example, `StateChangeStartHandler` and it's dependencies are not getting properly initialized. If anyone could explain more about this I would really be happy.